# How to read the bytes of an image resource located inside a nested JAR?

Tags: java, wildfly, inputstream, ear

I am struggling while trying to read the bytes of a PNG image bundled with the resources of a JAR. The file is located in the `src/main/resources` directory.

Here is my code so far:

```
byte[] bytes = {};
final InputStream defaultImageStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/defaultLogo.png");
new DataInputStream(defaultImageStream).readFully(bytes);
```

The code is executed on a Wildfly 12 server, located in a JAR included in the EAR as an EJB.

It seems than instead of retrieving the resource I asked for, `getResourceAsStream`  returns the enclosing jar:

[image]

**How can I get that image?**

Additional info:

- I tried both with an exploded and non-epxloded JAR in the EAR. Same results.
- The path to the resource seems correct. Prefixing it by "/resources" ends in the method returning NULL.
- I tried using the Class' classloader instead of the thread context's one. Same results.
- I envisioned going through all the entries of the enclosed JAR myself, but this both seems overkill and difficult: since I have a `JarInputStream` and no `JarFile`, how would I read the data corresponding to an entry?

Comment: Why do you believe that it is the enclosing jar? It looks like this is a stream `ZipFileInflaterInputStream` that reads from *inside* the jar.

Comment: As far as I know class ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream represents an InputStream for a single file inside a zip file, so it seems to be working correctly

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  @KonradBotor  You're right. I delved a bit more in the DIS. It turns out that `readFully(byte[] b)` will only read until the length of the recieving byte array. So, here, 0 bytes. *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is working as intended. Looking at the DataInputStream instance isn't going to tell you much. Look at the content, I think it is the image you want.

Comment: You're right. My mistake was not in the resource retrieval, it was in the bytes extraction. `readFully(byte[] b)` will only read until the length... of b, not of the inputstream.

Answer (score -1):

You're thinking correctly, the `JarInputStream` would server the purpose for you.

Your code should be something like below--

```
 try {
        JarInputStream jarIS = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                "jarfilePath"));

        JarEntry entry = null;
        while ((entry = jarIS.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
            String name = entry.getName();
            if (name.endsWith("defaultLogo.png")) {
                System.out.println( "You got the PNG File"+entry.getAttributes().toString() );
                //Now handle your stream as per your requirement.

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: This solution is necessary only if the JAR is not on the class path.

Comment: @Steve11235 thank you for pointing out, but I didn't say, you mast have to use `InputStream(FileInput("file"))` the code I suggested is place holder, it could be replaced with `CurentContext.classloader()`. Though I will modify the answer based on your feedback.